# ComboBox strange behaviour (JavaFX 8)

Tags: java, combobox, javafx, components

I have this code in start method:

```
ObservableList<StringBuilder> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
list.add(new StringBuilder("0"));
list.add(new StringBuilder("1"));
list.add(new StringBuilder("2"));
list.add(new StringBuilder("3"));
list.add(new StringBuilder("4"));
list.add(new StringBuilder("5"));
list.add(new StringBuilder("6"));
list.add(new StringBuilder("7"));
list.add(new StringBuilder("8"));
list.add(new StringBuilder("9"));

ComboBox<StringBuilder> combo = new ComboBox<>(list);
Button change = new Button("change");
change.setOnAction((event) -> {
    list.set(5, new StringBuilder("-"));
});

BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane(combo, null, null, change, null);
Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```

I start my program and select second item and then I click on "change" button several times. Nothing happens and it's good. 
But If I select item "6" and click on "change" button then comboBox autoselects next item ("7"). 
Why does it happen?

Then we can change the row

`list.set(5, new StringBuilder("-");`

on

```
list.remove(5);
```

Then if I select item "2" and click "change" button then nothing happens. And again if I select item "9" and click "change" button then comboBox autoselects previous item ("8").

I expect that if I just change item, i.e. use set method of list, then comboBox doesn't change selection. How to cope with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure why this is happening, this might have something to do with the way `ComboBox` handles `ObservabeList` in it. But this cannot be replicated using `ChoiceBox`. Can you please raise a [`JIRA`](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com) with the JavaFX team, so that they can have a look at it?

As a turnaround, you may do the following in your code to fix it temporarily :

```
ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<String>(list);
Button change = new Button("change");
change.setOnAction((event) -> {
    StringBuilder str = combo.getValue();
    list.set(5, new String("-"));
    combo.setValue(str);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ChoiceBox in this case, it worked fine to me. Just replace ComboBox with ChoiceBox. But pressing the button when 5 is selected doesn't refresh the header to "-".

Answer (score 1):

I think this is probably `bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8087838` : `ComboBox: Root observable list changing causes very strange selection issues, which is sort of fixed on Java 9, for general availablility Sep 2016`. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38342046/how-to-use-a-sortedlist-with-javafx-editable-combobox-strange-onaction-events) question