# JavaFX editable ComboBox with history function

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I am attempting to make a JavaFX `ComboBox` that remembers the history of the entries entered by the user.  Adding new items works, but selecting from the drop-down does not.

In a nutshell, I am trying to get the control to

1. Add the most recently typed entry to the top, as the first item of the `ComboBox`.
2. Clear the `TextField` portion for the next entry.
3. Upon selecting an item from the `ComboBox`, will copy selection to the `TextField`, without modifying the `ComboBox`'s items.

Adding new items works fine, it's the copying a previous entry to the field is proving frustrating.

The only similar problem I could find was [javafx combobox items list issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32118589/javafx-combobox-items-list-issue), whose solution unfortunately did not fix my problem.

Code

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;


public class HistoryField<String> extends ComboBox<String> {
    public final static int DEFAULT_MAX_ENTRIES = 256;

    //Data members
    private int maxSize;
    private final ObservableList<String> history;

   //Default constructor
    public HistoryField() {
        this(DEFAULT_MAX_ENTRIES, (String[]) null);
    }

    public HistoryField(int maxSize, String ... entries) {
        super(FXCollections.observableList(new LinkedList<>()));
        this.setEditable(true);

        this.maxSize = maxSize;
        this.history = this.getItems();


        //Populate list with entries (if any)
        if (entries != null) {
            for (int i = 0; ((i < entries.length) && (i < this.maxSize)); i++) {
                this.history.add(entries[i]);
            }
         }

        this.valueProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) -> {
            if ((oldValue == null) && (newValue != null)) {                
                if (this.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() < 0) {
                    this.getItems().add(0, newValue);
                    this.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                }
            } else {

                //This throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
                this.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Test class

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HistoryFieldTest extends Application {
    private HistoryField<String> historyField;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {        
        this.historyField = new HistoryField<>();

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setBottom(historyField);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setTitle("History Field Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is your problem? Your code talks about an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, but your question does not indicate if that's where you're having trouble. What exactly does not work?

Comment: @zephyr that was what I expected would apply the selection and then "reset" the `ComboBox` i.e. get it out of editing mode so new entries could again be added.  Since it worked in the first part of the `if`-block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following updated `HistoryField` class. There are a couple of changes I made.

First of all, instead of passing a `varargs` of Strings, just pass the array you want.  You can then convert the array to a `List` ready for the `ComboBox` using `Arrays.asList()` method.

Also, I streamlined the process of adding a new item to the list. The listener will now only add an item to the list if it doesn't already exist.

You also never handled the `max_size` situation, so I added a simple check to remove the older entry once the `max_size` has been reached.

The field is only cleared if an item is added to the list; it is unclear from your question if that is the desired behavior.

```
public class HistoryField extends ComboBox<String> {

    private final static int DEFAULT_MAX_ENTRIES = 5;

    //Data members
    private int maxSize;
    private final ObservableList<String> history;

    //Default constructor
    public HistoryField() {
        this(DEFAULT_MAX_ENTRIES, null);
    }

    /* Changed parameter to an array instead of list of Strings */
    public HistoryField(int maxSize, String[] entries) {
        this.setEditable(true);

        this.maxSize = maxSize;

        /* Convert the passed array to a list and populate the dropdown */
        if (entries != null) {
            history = FXCollections.observableArrayList(Arrays.asList(entries));
        } else {
            history = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        }

        setItems(history);

        this.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue != null) {

                // Check if value already exists in list
                if (!this.history.contains(newValue)) {
                    this.history.add(0, newValue);

                    // If the max_size has been reached, remove the oldest item from the list
                    if (this.history.size() > maxSize) {
                        this.history.remove(history.size() - 1);
                    }

                    System.out.println(history);

                    // Clear the selection when new item is added
                    this.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But with your code, how would one apply a selected item to the text field, and add something?
When I add some items, and then click on an item, it won't allow me to add any additional items.
E.g. given list "alpha", "beta", "gamma," if I select "beta," I can't then delete it and add "delta"

Comment: The reason for that is because you were initially only allowing an additional item if `oldValue == null`. See my edit where I removed that portion of the `if` statement. You can now make that change.

Comment: If you are looking to be able to also **delete** "beta" by typing over it, that would require a bit more handling and would be better suited to a new question.

Comment: there's no need to change the signature of the constructor - getItems().setAll(strings) will do fine, without irrelevant lines of code. @SKNB don't quite get why you keep an alias to the items? history is just complicating the code without benefit that I see ;)

Comment: @zephyr Thank you! That cleared things up nicely.  My only other issue would be adding duplicate items, e.g. if the user has entered first "foo" and "bar", he should be able to enter "foo" again.  So then it would be "foo" "bar" "foo".  But I think that you've given me more than enough to go on for right now.  Thanks again

Comment: @kleopatra Well...you're correct, it is unnecessary.  I had originally planned on having the history entries displayed as `TextFlow`s, corresponding to an internal master list of `String`s for expediency.  But one nightmare at a time.  Thanks for the tip about the constructor

Comment: @SKNB - If you'd like to allow duplicates, just remove the `if (!this.history.contains(newValue))` statement block.

Comment: @kleopatra - I agree changing the signature and keeping an alias to the list is unnecessary. I sometimes do that in my own code and explanations just for readability.